# Should a fragment always be placed on top of an empty activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

In my app, I am putting a `Fragment` on top of an `Activity` that contains a `RecyclerView` and a `FloatingActionButton`. 
This comes with a few problems, which can be solved, but the solutions feel kinda hacky:

For example:

1. By default, the `Fragment`'s background is transparent, so we have to give it a background color.
2. Buttons peak through the `Fragment`, so we have to raise the `elevation` of the `FrameLayout` or make the buttons invisible.
3. Clicks on the `Fragment`'s background go through to the `Activity`, so we have to set the fragment's layout to `clickable`.

Considering these and other problems, is it bad practice to put a fragment on top of an activity that contains buttons and other views?

Answer (score 1):

> is it bad practice to put a fragment on top of an activity that contains buttons and other views?

Short Answer is: No. UI/UX development is a very personalized and subjective thing. Usually there aren't much constraints on how you structure the elements, rather, its about how do you handle the interactions (events, actions, re-usability etc).

Coming to your scenario, subjectively speaking, divide your activity in 2 containers ( `Layouts`; one for your activity UI elements and other for fragment) and hide the activity UI container when `fragment` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Where would you handle the activity layout visibility, because it's a bit tricky with the back button.

Comment: You are welcome. I'd use an interface to have a communication channel between activity and fragment. While your activity implements the interfce ( lets say "UIToggleInterface") you can call "UIToggleInterface.showActivityUI ()" method in "onDestroy()" method of your fragment.

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if it helped.